# Combination of conditional statements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, conditional-statements

I have 2 sets of 3 conditions each. 
Let a,b,c be one set of conditions and x,y,z be the other set. I need to evaluate the following

```
if(a && x)
..... 
else if(a && y) 
..... 
else if(a && z)
.....
```

In the same way 3 conditions with b and 3 with c.

What is the best way to evaluate the conditions without writing all the combinations?

Update :

I am making a game in Unity. The conditions a,b,c check whether the **x** position of the player is within a certain range compared to a ball's position and conditions x,y,z do the same for **y** position. Based on the correct condition(from the combination ax,ay,az,bx,by,bz,cx,cy,cz) one animation state(out of 9) is selected. So each condition would produce a different result.

Update :
I ended up making two functions that evaluate the two sets of conditions and each returns an enum on which bitwise OR is done to get the final state.

Comment: Will the conditions always cycle through `x`, `y`, `z` for `a`, `b` and `c` in that order? I'm thinking something clumsy involving an array of lambda expressions. Harder to read and maintain than `if`/`else`. Generally a bad idea unless there were a lot more than 9 combinations and some pattern to the code that goes between them.

Comment: I'm also thinking it depends on what it is that will be carried out in the various sets of conditions.  If there are no similarities between what's being carried out, why not write all the combinations?  If there are similarities that you can use to reduce combinations, OP needs to add more details to the question.

Comment: I agree with previous comment, this question as it stands can not be answered. If each combination needs specific code, then writing out all cases is a must. If there is commonality, it should be part of the question. Voting to close until the question until more information is provided.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought would be to at least test the first group of conditions first, and then test the second group of conditions afterwards.  While this is not an answer that avoids writing all nine if statements, you will on average reduce the amount of if statements being checked.

```
if (a) 
{
    if (x) { }
    else if (y) { }
    else if (z) { }
}
else if (b)
{
    if (x) { }
    else if (y) { }
    else if (z) { }
}
else if (c)
{
    if (x) { }
    else if (y) { }
    else if (z) { }
}
```

Comment: @Aominè I'm just thinking that if you write out all combinations in the pattern the OP started, validating for e.g. "c" and "z" to be true will be the nineth validation.  In the case above using elimination, it will be the sixth.

Comment: Thanks. I had thought of this method. But since the x,y,z conditions were repeated I thought there might be a better way to do it. Based on the other suggestions this seems to be the best option.

Comment: I ended up making two functions that evaluate the two sets of conditions and each returns an enum on which bitwise OR is done to get the final state.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it using Linq expressions, Linq expressions is a way to define expressions dynamically where you can do multiple operations on them. i used here a fake conditional expression that takes a number as an argument just for the sake of demonstration. first define each condition in a method or directly within you code. then put all those into arrays, each conditions set to an array. then two foreach that executes the expressions.

```
int num = 20;

        ConditionalExpression[] firstSet = { ExpressionA(num), ExpressionB(num), ExpressionC(num) };
        ConditionalExpression[] secondSet = { ExpressionX(num), ExpressionY(num), ExpressionZ(num) };

        foreach(var firstSetExpression in firstSet)
            foreach (var secondSetExpression in secondSet)
            {
                var result1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(firstSetExpression.Test).Compile();
                var result2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(secondSetExpression.Test).Compile();

                if (result1.Invoke() && result2.Invoke())
                { 
                    // do your thing here 
                }
            }
```

Where you define expressions for each condition within a method, for example like this:

```
private static ConditionalExpression ExpressionA(int num)
        {
             return Expression.Condition(
                          Expression.Constant(num > 10),
                          Expression.Constant("num is greater than 10"),
                          Expression.Constant("num is smaller than 10")
                        );
        }
```

this can be even optimized in many ways, but only to get you started.

Update: This is another way for who dont like to compile at runtime. using delegates:

```
Func<int, bool>[] firstSet = new Func<int,bool> [] { ExpressionA(), ExpressionA(), ExpressionA() };
            Func<int, bool>[] secondSet = new Func<int, bool>[] { ExpressionA(), ExpressionA(), ExpressionA() };

            foreach(var firstSetExpression in firstSet)
                foreach (var secondSetExpression in secondSet)
                {
                    if (firstSetExpression.Invoke(20) && secondSetExpression.Invoke(20))
                    { 
                        // do your thing here 
                    }
                }
...
...
...

private static Func<int, bool> ExpressionA()
        {
             return (x) => x > 10;
        }
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Compiling at the run time? Does not sound exiting to me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate all possible combinations. Since you deal with Booleans, each gives you 2 options. Then the simplest possible combination of 2 bools results to 2 x 2 = 4 combinations. Generally saying, K = 2^n, where n represent number of booleans you deal with.

Would I be you, I would stick to `Tuple<bool, bool, bool>` and nested `for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)` cycles (for n parameters n cycles needed).

2. Then I would feed a list of `Tuple<Predicate<Tuple<bool, bool, bool>>, Action>` which pairs predicate with callback that should trigger when predicates equals true.
3. Rest could be achieved with Linq. Something alike `possibleCombinationsList.Select(tripleOfBooleans => predicatesAndCallbacksList.Single(predicateAndCallback => predicateAndCallback.Item1(tripleOfBooleans) == true)).Sinle().Item2();`

Have fun.

Comment: I am doing this in Unity and Tuple is not supported. Sorry for not mentioning this earlier.

Comment: @Shyam Why matters? There still options, starting from `bool[]` and ending up with custom tuple-like class.

Comment: I ended up making two functions that evaluate the two sets of conditions and each returns an enum on which bitwise OR is done to get the final state.